# Bokeh categorical x-axis alignment on scatter

Tags: python, bokeh

I have a scatter with a categorical x-axis, but my circles don't align with the axis.  This code example replicates the issue:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

data = [[1,12],[2,8]]
x_axis_rng = ['VAL 1','VAL 2']

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['x','y']

chart_data = ColumnDataSource(df)
print(chart_data)
plot = figure(title='Example',
          x_axis_label='x',
          y_axis_label='y', 
          x_range=x_axis_rng)

plot.circle('x',
        'y',
        size=10,
        source=chart_data)

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('x', '@x'),('y', '@y')])
plot.add_tools(hover)

output_file('test.html')
show(plot)
```

I read about offsetting the x-axis, but I could not get that to work, and it didn't seem like ti should be necessary in this case?

Any help appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an axis/range with categorical factors, but are giving circle coordinates as numbers. If you want to position glyphs according to categorical values, the coordinates have to reflect that:

```
data = [['VAL 1', 12],['VAL 2', 8]]
```

[image]